# Particular solutions to $y''+4y=\cos^2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the equation above but after I have solved the homogeneous part:
$$y_h=A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x), \; A,B\in\mathbb{C},$$
I don't get it how to find $y_p$. I am told to deduct it from $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{2}$, but I don't understand how. Can you help me tho?

Comment: Note that $\cos 2x$ solves the homogeneous equation and also appears in the nonhomogeneity term.  Do you know how to modify it to get a particular solution in such a case?

Comment: No I can't find out the way to get a particular solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the hint means is that first of all you literally replace the right-hand side of the equation with $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{2}$, so now you're looking for a particular solution to
$$y''+4y=\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{2}.$$
Moreover, by the superposition principle for particular solutions (see e.g. [here](https://www.math24.net/second-order-linear-nonhomogeneous-differential-equations-constant-coefficients/) or [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx)), we may seek separate solutions to
$$y''+4y=\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) \quad \text{and} \quad y''+4y=\frac{1}{2}$$
and then add them together.

- For the first equation $y''+4y=\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)$, note that $\lambda=\pm2i$ were the roots of the characteristic equation, so you should set up a particular solution in the form $y_{p1}(x)=x(A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x))$.
- For the second equation $y''+4y=\frac{1}{2}$, note that $\lambda=0$ was not a root of the characteristic equation, so you should set up a particular solution in the form $y_{p2}(x)=A$.

Comment: Ok I think I see but with the principle of superposition shouldn't I find 2 particular solutions of each new ODE as it is a 2nd order ?

Comment: @Alexis: Yes, that's exactly what I said. You find two particular solutions, so to speak. More precisely, you find one particular solution to each of the separate non-homogeneous equations: $y_{p1}$ for the first and $y_{p2}$ for the second. Then a particular solution to the original non-homogeneous equation will be $y_p=y_{p1}+y_{p2}$.

Comment: Alright then I get it thank you very much for your help !